# GCS Bucket HMAC randomly 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I am reading parquet files from google cloud storage buckets using pyspark. Everything works fine till I am trying to get data from different buckets - 3 files.
When reading third file I am getting:

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null

**If I change the order of files I am reading (e.g. the third one is first) all works perfectly fine.**

My spark settings:

```
        spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", configuration.user)
        spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", configuration.password)
        spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", configuration.endpoint)
        spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
            "fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
        )
        spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
```

I am using:
hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.704.jar
spark-hadoop-cloud_2.13-3.2.0.jar

Answer (score 2):

And yes I found the solution. I was wrongly setting the buckets access shall be:

```
   spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.s3a.bucket.{bucket_name}.endpoint", configuration.endpoint)
    spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.s3a.bucket.{bucket_name}.access.key", configuration.user)
    spark_session.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.s3a.bucket.{bucket_name}.secret.key", configuration.password)
```

And remember kids, 8 hours of debugging can save you 0.5 hour of reading the documentation.

> Configuring different S3 buckets with Per-Bucket Configuration
> Different S3 buckets can be accessed with different S3A client configurations. This allows for different endpoints, data read and write strategies, as well as login details.
> All fs.s3a options other than a small set of unmodifiable values (currently fs.s3a.impl) can be set on a per bucket basis. The bucket specific option is set by replacing the fs.s3a. prefix on an option with fs.s3a.bucket.BUCKETNAME., where BUCKETNAME is the name of the bucket.
> When connecting to a bucket, all options explicitly set will override the base fs.s3a. values.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Storing_secrets_with_Hadoop_Credential_Providers